# Need to generate serial number

Tags: python-2.7, ksh

I have requirement to generate 4 character serial numbers like below in Python or Shell Scripting.

```
Serial number should start from 0001, 0002..... when reached 999 it should generate A001,A002....A999, then B001, so on.
```

I tried below code in Python, but its not fully working, After few number it starts generating 5 characters..

```
def excel_format(num):
    res = ""
    while num:
        mod = (num - 1) % 26
        res = chr(65 + mod) + res
        num = (num - mod) // 26
    return res

def full_format(num, d=3):
    set_flag = 0
    chars = num // (10**d-1) + 1 # this becomes   A..ZZZ
    if len(excel_format(chars)) >= 2:
        set_flag = 1
    if len(excel_format(chars)) > 2:
        set_flag = 2

    if set_flag == 1:
        d = 2

    chars = num // (10 ** d - 1) + 1  # this becomes   A..ZZZ
    digit = num %  (10**d-1) + 1 # this becomes 001..999
    return excel_format(chars) + "{:0{}d}".format(digit, d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(1,10001):
        unique_code = full_format(j, d=3)
        print('Unique Code is =>', unique_code)
```

Comment: We can't help you in code writing instead we can help you in where you are stuck! so please show us your effort.

Answer (score 1):

This Python code will generate the required 4-character (Unique_code) serial numbers:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re

for i in range(1,10000):
    if (i < 1000):
       print ("i =", str(i).zfill(4))
    else:
       m = re.findall(r'(\d)(\d\d\d)', str(i))
       code = 64+int(m[0][0])
       print ("i =",i, "Unique_code =", chr(code) + m[0][1])
```

Excerpts from output:

```
i = 0001
i = 0002
...
i = 0999
i = 1000 Unique_code = A000
i = 1001 Unique_code = A001
i = 1002 Unique_code = A002
...
i = 1997 Unique_code = A997
i = 1998 Unique_code = A998
i = 1999 Unique_code = A999
i = 2000 Unique_code = B000
i = 2001 Unique_code = B001
i = 2002 Unique_code = B002
i = 2003 Unique_code = B003
...
i = 9997 Unique_code = I997
i = 9998 Unique_code = I998
i = 9999 Unique_code = I999
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar enough with Python but since you've flagged ksh

```
#!/bin/ksh

typeset -Z3 sn

Letter=( 0 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z )


Index=0

while [[ $Index -lt 28 ]]; do
    sn=0
    while [[ $sn -lt 1000 ]]; do
        print ${Letter[$Index]}$sn
        ((sn++))
    done
    ((Index++))
done
```

Comment: Thanks, but it wnt work as expected. Its created non-unique numbers in loop...

Comment: Isn't it what you ask for ? Sorry, then not sure to understand your question then.